# Getting only integers when dividing a pandas dataframe by a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, integer

I am trying to divide a dataframe by a pandas series and the result is only giving ones everywhere.

Here is the example :

This is my dataframe df

[image: This is my dataframe df]

This is my pandas series s

[image: This is my pandas series s]

this is what I am getting result

[image: this is what I am getting result]

I am using pandas division.

```
df.divide(s, axis=1).
```

I tried to use as.type(float), it didnt change anything.

Even when I am looking individually to each column it's giving me the same result.

```
df.iloc[:,0].astype(float)/float(s.iloc[0])
```

It's giving a column only with ones.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your data as text so that others can use it directly to replicate your problem.

Comment: I'm using python3 and `df.divide(s, axis=1)` works for me and gives me decimal result. What python version are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.6.5

Comment: Actually I tried all the possible transformations, I am still getting integer values when dividing a dataframe by anything else

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and realized I had my float format set to display 0 digits to the right of the decimal. You can adjust your float format like this:

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

Where 2 is the number of decimals to display.